# Should.js: check if two arrays contain same strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, should.js

I have two arrays:

```
var a = ['a', 'as', 'sa'];
var b = ['sa', 'a', 'as'];
```

Is there anything special in shouldJS to test if these two arrays have same items? Anything Like

```
should(a).be.xyz(b)
```

that can test them? Here, xyz is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive, but possibly sufficient solution would be to sort the arrays before comparing them:

```
should(a.sort()).be.eql(b.sort())
```

Note that [`sort()` works in-place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), mutating the original arrays.

Comment: This answer is not correct. .equal uses === for reference equality. Need to use .eql.

Comment: @denbardadym Thanks for the note, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this with `should`'s `Assertion.add` feature.  For example:

```
var a = ['a', 'as', 'sa'];
var b = ['sa', 'a', 'as'];

should.Assertion.add('haveSameItems', function(other) {
  this.params = { operator: 'to be have same items' };

  this.obj.forEach(item => {
    //both arrays should at least contain the same items
    other.should.containEql(item);
  });
  // both arrays need to have the same number of items
  this.obj.length.should.be.equal(other.length);
});

//passes
a.should.haveSameItems(b);

b.push('d');

// now it fails
a.should.haveSameItems(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improved version of Michael's code:

```
should.Assertion.add("haveSameItems", function (other) {
    this.params = { operator: "to be have same items" };

    const a = this.obj.slice(0);
    const b = other.slice(0);

    function deepSort(objA, objB) {
        const a = JSON.stringify(objA);
        const b = JSON.stringify(objB);

        return (a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0));
    }

    a.sort(deepSort);
    b.sort(deepSort);

    a.should.be.deepEqual(b);
});
```